# Ошибка при запуске приложения через андроид студию

Tags: android

При попытке запустить приложение на телефоне через Андроид студию возникает ошибка:

```
Installation failed with message Failed to establish session.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.
WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!
Do you want to uninstall the existing application?
```

Выбор любого варианта ОК/Отмена приводит к завершению.
Вот лог:

```
12:45   Gradle build finished in 15s 914ms
12:45   Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
12:45   Gradle build finished in 4s 986ms
12:46   Session 'app': Error Installing APKs
```

У кого есть идеи как исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Скорей всего тут может быть проблема в:

1. Надо отключить в студии "Instant Run". File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Instant Run
2. Надо включить режим дебага на телефоне
3. Удалить предыдущую apk-шку с телефона.

Answer (score 1):

Шаг 1. Перейдите в «Настройка» → найдите «Параметры разработчика» в    Системе и нажмите.

Шаг 2: ВКЛЮЧИТЕ «Проверка приложений через USB» в    разделе «Отладка».

Шаг 3. Попробуйте «Запустить приложение» в Android    Studio еще раз!

```
and you should also TURN ON following fields inside "Developer option"
```

1: ВКЛЮЧИТЬ -> «Установить через USB»

Если вы используете телефон Xiaomi, то проблема решается немного иначе.

Так же вы можете просто попытаться удалить с телефона данное приложение, и попытаться установить его заново через Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо!
Помогло:
Отключить и включить заново режим "Отладка по USB" на телефоне.

Я просто сразу не написал, что телефон как и студия несколько раз перегружались и приложение было удалено.